# switching between different classes for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two data sources, and two different classes for custom cells in my table. 
I want by pressing one button to switch between sources and classes and update my UITableView accordingly.

Unfortunately It works only one time I switch from one set to another. It doesn't return back.

Hope my code will help to explain what I mean:

```
var displayMode : Int = 1

 @objc func tappedButton(_ sender: UIButton?) {
        if displayMode == 1 {
          displayMode = 2
          myTable.reloadData()
        } else {
            displayMode = 1
          myTable.reloadData()
        } 
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
  cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  if displayMode == 1  {    
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId,
             forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Class1

  cell.taskTitle.text = source1.text


  return cell
  } 

  else {

  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId,
             forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Class2

  cell.taskTitle.text = source2.text


  return cell

  } 
}
```

Should I delete table cells before changing mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You need to create 2 separate classes for cells:

```
class FirstCellClass: UITableViewCell {}

class SecondCellClass: UITableViewCell {}
```

2) Then register the cells(or add cells in Storyboard):

```
tableView.register(FirstCellClass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: FirstCellClass.self))
tableView.register(SecondCellClass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: SecondCellClass.self))
```

3) Check display mode and return specific cell `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and items count in `numberOfRowsInSection`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch displayMode {
    case .first:
        return firstDataSource.count
    case .second:
        return secondDataSource.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch displayMode {
    case .first:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: String(describing: FirstCellClass.self),
            for: indexPath
        ) as! FirstCellClass
        configureFirstCell(cell)
        return cell
    case .second:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: String(describing: SecondCellClass.self),
            for: indexPath
        ) as! SecondCellClass
        configureSecondCell(cell)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Marking this question as correct because it was not working eith different identifiers. Very important to register cells correctly using different classes names ( I was using same class name when was registering cells)

Answer (score 2):

You use the same cellID in

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId,
         forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Class1
```

and

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId,
         forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Class2
```

Should be two different cells for 2 different classes (2 different IDS)

Comment: So I need to register two custom cells for my table and then use their ids correct?

Comment: register 2 custom cells with 2 different ids and cast each cell to the corresponding class in cellForRow

Comment: Yes. The function `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:forIndexPath:)` only knows the identifier. It goes and looks at the storyboard, instantiates the cell with that identifier, and returns it, regardless of what class that table view cell is. You can't cast it to 2 different types and expect that to work. You need 2 different identifiers that match the cell types you have defined in your storyboard.